# Possible bug: on hold item missing from the main question list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

I ask because [The woman and the heavy bloodguilt [on hold]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17981/the-woman-and-the-heavy-bloodguilt) is not present (though it was edited 15 hours ago at time of writing, so it should be there).

However, there are other on hold items present (eg [Would this be believing in my own works? [on hold]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17990/would-this-be-believing-in-my-own-works) from *16 hours ago*). So perhaps this is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. The difference is in the vote patterns on the questions. You will find all the questions show up if you specifically go to the questions tag and sort by active or newest, but the home page has several filters to keep junk from being the first thing that new visitors see. I believe the cutoff for <strike>closed</strike> any question to be hidden from the home page is a vote score of -4 or below.

Comment: Ha ha, just saw the message, *"You can accept an answer in 3 seconds"*.

Comment: not just closed. all questions are removed from the homepage at -4

Comment: @waxeagle I actually wondered about that but couldn't find a reference and ran out of time, so I put that in just to be safe.